# How do I shift col of numpy matrix to last col?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Say I have a numpy matrix as such:

```
[[1, 3, 4, 7, 8]
 [5, 6, 8, 2, 6]
 [2, 9, 3, 3, 6]
 [7, 1, 9, 3, 5]]
```

I want to shift column 2 of the matrix to the last column:

```
[[1, 4, 7, 8, 3]
 [5, 8, 2, 6, 6]
 [2, 3, 3, 6, 9]
 [7, 9, 3, 5, 1]]
```

How exactly do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a list of columns, then use that to index the array. Here, `new_column_order` uses a range to get all columns before `col`, another range to get all columns after `col`, then puts `col` at the end. Each range object is unpacked via `*` into the new column list.

```
x = np.array([[1, 3, 4, 7, 8], 
              [5, 6, 8, 2, 6], 
              [2, 9, 3, 3, 6], 
              [7, 1, 9, 3, 5]])
col = 1 # 2nd column
new_column_order = [*range(col), *range(col + 1, x.shape[-1]), col]
x_new = x[:, new_column_order]
print(x_new)
```

**Output:**

```
[[1 4 7 8 3]
 [5 8 2 6 6]
 [2 3 3 6 9]
 [7 9 3 5 1]]
```

Comment: Woah. I'm new to python. Do you mind explaining what the x_new line is doing? Thanks!

Comment: @VickConan I slightly modified the example code and added some prose. Let me know if I can help clarify anything better.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Use `numpy.roll`:

```
arr[:, 1:] = np.roll(arr[:, 1:], -1, 1)
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 4, 7, 8, 3],
       [5, 8, 2, 6, 6],
       [2, 3, 3, 6, 9],
       [7, 9, 3, 5, 1]])
```

How:

`np.roll` takes three arguments: `a`, `shift` and `axis`:

```
np.roll(a = arr[:, 1:], shift = -1, axis = 1)
```

This means that, take `arr[:, 1:]`(all rows, all columns from 1), and shift it one unit to the left (-1. to the right would be +1), along the axis 1 (i.e. columnar shift, axis 0 would be row shift).

`np.roll`, as name states, is a *circular shift*. One unit shift will make last column to be the first, and so on.

Comment: Hi Chris, I'm new to python. Do you mind explaining what that line is doing? Thanks.

Comment: @VickConan Please take a look at the updated _How_ part :)